# Parsing a date string containing milliseconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to parse date string to date object which has milliseconds in it. For example my date string is:
2014-11-30T00:00:01:000+0530 , not the last three zeros for milliseconds. when I try to parse this using Date.parse(), I am getting NAN.

Comment: you have a wrong symbol in it. Milliseconds are separated using a dot not a colon.

Comment: This is not a valid date string.
Trying `new Date("2014-11-30T00:00:01:000+0530");` in console gives 'Invalid Date'.

Answer (score 4):

Try using *ISO 8601* syntax, note how *miliseconds* are seperated by `.`, not a `:`

```
2014-11-30T00:00:01:000+0530 // your syntax
2014-11-30T00:00:01.000+0530 // ISO 8601 syntax
```

i.e.

```
Date.parse('2014-11-30T00:00:01.000+0530');
// 1417285801000
```